# Kendo formatting within input - Change color of currency symbol

Tags: jquery, input, kendo-ui, textbox, currency

Hi I have an input tag in my html

```
<input class="k-formatted-value k-input" type="text">
```

The value of my input is `$13.00`. I used the kendo formatting in adding the currency in my text box.

```
$(".k-formatted-value ").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "c",
    decimals: 2
});
```

I would like the currency symbol to be color blue and the numeric color black. How can I do this in jquery?

Comment: You can't do that as HTML does not support multiple colour text within a single input element. Also your title seems to describe a different problem...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way I know of to style inputs seperately is to make a "fake" input and hide the real one, like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/o34swb1j/2/

However, this gets kind of messy and doesn't always work as expected (missing blinker/cursor/caret, having to style the input and divs to act like one)

Honestly, I would solve the issue you are having with CSS instead of some heavy plugin, or even javascript for that matter.. You don't need the currency within the value, right? (would seem odd)
So, solving this with css, you could make it out to just let the currency overlay the input, without actually being in it, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/r23r9j0b/

The issue with this: A part of your input will be unclickable (the overlay)

The fix: A small jQuery event handler and some css to make sure it feels like a part of the input.

html:

```
<form>
  <div class="inputWrap">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" />
    <span class="currency">&euro;</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.inputWrap .currency').on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents('.inputWrap').find('input').focus();
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inputWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.inputWrap input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 33px;
}

.inputWrap input,
.inputWrap .currency {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.inputWrap .currency {
  color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

.inputWrap .currency:hover {
  cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: I used kendo. There is no span element or such tag when using this, that's why I'm having trouble.

Comment: Oh.. I see, you're limited to working only with Kendo? You can't implement your own HTML? Sounds like a very restricting framework, which I know nothing about. I guess I can't help then, sorry! I saw this: `<input class="k-formatted-value k-input" type="text">` so I assumed you could put a `<span>` underneath it.